# What type of Hayes hydraulic brake is this?

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

I am having trouble finding out which brake set from Hayes this is. I think they are from around 2003 or so. The brake levers were spray painted and I can't see anything about them anywhere. I'm trying to buy brake pads and a bleed kit for them, so if you have any bleed kit recommendations let me know!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have a set of Hayes HFX Max G1, you can use [these](https://www.hayesdiscbrake.com/products/brake-pads/mag-9-mx1-semi-metallic/) pads. Surprisingly, a lot of other people experience the same issue as you.